What do we call someone who converts a thesis into a book?
I am writing an appointment letter to a freelancer who is comissioned to transform a thesis/disseratation into a book.

Subject: Appointment as a thesis-into-book _______.

The problem is I have no idea to fill in the blank. I know I can just paraphrase the sentence to avoid such an issue but my publisher won't let me do that.
I have come up with several options, namely:

Thesis-into-book converter
Thesis-into-book specialist
Thesis-into-book consultant
Thesis-into-book editor

However, and I don't want to call them a specialist or an editor; those terms are reserved for specific roles. "Thesis-into-book converter", "thesis-into-book changer", or "thesis-into-book transformer" does not sound right to me. But please let me know if I am wrong.

Since you are stuck with thesis-into-book as a premodifier, your question is not really about how one might refer to such a person but how to deal with your publisher's restrictions. Why doesn't your publisher tell you what they want you to say there?

@TimR The publisher is not based in the US or in the UK. We have "perombak tesis kepada buku" in our native language, but in this case, it needs to be written in English.

You aren’t obliged to noun everything. Why not benefit from that under appreciated feature of English, the verb? Appointment to transform a thesis into a book.

Wait  a minute, Why is the word appointment even being used? Publishers don't appoint people to write books. They might commission them for example or contract them. The thesis author has been asked to etc.

What part of the process is the person actually doing? That's going to impact quite heavily on what term is used. I'd use "consultant" in the absence of anything more specific, maybe you could explain why that's rejected.

If you write a book based on a thesis, you are just an author. thesis-to-book author.

@Lambie  But not if you didn't write the thesis.  How about thesis-to-book doula?

It's not clear to me what you are asking.  I don't understand the role.  I don't know why you are writing the email, nor why your publisher has any say in the title of an email. I don't know what it means to change a thesis into a book.  The phrase "thesis-into-book" is markedly unnatural.  There's no way to make a natural sounding English sentence so there's no way to answer the question as it stands.

The thesis-to-book process has a number of specialist roles:

Developmental Editor - works closely with an author to shape and structure a manuscript.

Academic Editor - focuses on scholarly works, ensuring the content meets the standards and style guidelines of academic publishers.

Scholarly Publishing Consultant - guides academics through the entire publishing process, including adapting theses into books.


Other roles exist in the process, but mainly ones which would be involved in any kind of publishing, not just thesis-to-book. A "ghostwriter" for example would be someone who creates a book entirely based on the original work, but then the book is published in the original scholar's name.
Your own job descriptions are probably understandable (so long as the audience knows what 'thesis-to-book' means), but they are descriptions and may not actually be the job titles used and recognised in the industry.

The question is about what the person who wrote the thesis and then makes a book out of it is called. I'd call them: an author. A thesis-to-book author, for example.

@lambie No, that's the exact opposite of what it's about. The OP said it's the name of a "freelancer" who is commissioned only to "transform" it. They didn't create the thesis.

Yeah, my mistake but this is not: I am writing an appointment letter to a freelancer who is comissioned to transform a thesis/disseratation into a book. That person is still the author makes a thesis out of the book, regardless of who wrote the thesis. Those positions you list are irrelevant.

@Lambie An author is a person who creates an original work. If it is anything less than their work then other terms apply. They may be a ghostwriter, or an adaptor, a co-author or a research assistant. I've researched the terms included in my answer for the OP's specific context. I'll consider revising my answer if I'm presented with any solid contrary evidence.

The point is that your answer is about roles in publishing, which may or may not include thesis-based books.

I think it is unclear what the OP means, and so the question should be closed.
